# EF core 7 release database .sqlite problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using (porting from EF to EF Core) Entity framework Core 7, but I have a problem, I see that Entity framework Core 7 not release the database file.sqlite when the datacontext exit the using scope. Only when i close the main program the file is released.
Below my code:

```cs
using (var ctx = new DataAccessContextTool())
{
    ctx.MigrateAndSetAutodetectChanges();

    ctx.ToolData.ClearDbSet();
    //ctx.SaveChanges();

    int key = 0;
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    var tmp = objetToSave
        .Tool
        .Elements
        .Select(ele => 
            new DbTool { 
                Key = key++, 
                ProjectNum = ele.ProjectNum, 
                DataType = (int)ele.DataType, DataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ele, settings) 
            }).ToList();

    ctx.ToolData.AddRange(tmp);

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    //ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA user_version = 2");

}
```

With the "old" EF with this call at the end it close the DB but the EF Core doesn't works

```cs
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

There is a way to release the DB with EFCore? Do you have any idea or settings to resolve my problem? thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. How `DataAccessContextTool` is setup, especially the connection?

Comment: Have you tried to call `ctx.Dispose()` after you finished all operations over the DB?

Comment: @GuillermoEspert why do you think `using` is not enough?

Comment: @GuruStron you're completely right I clearly ignored this line

Comment: Not sure, but try `SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools()` at the end.

Comment: Nothing works :(

Comment: I have made some tests. Can you put `SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools();` inside `using` block as the last line. It closses all file handles for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to a breaking change introduced with efcore 6 (see this link for more information: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26580). SQLite now pools connections so when a connection is "closed" it is kept available for another use. This behaviour can be changed using the `Pooling=false` option in the connection string. This restores the previous behaviour and a connection is closed when a DbContext is destroyed.